# MySQL Query is fine, doesn't give a value or an error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to find how to check if a variable called active is equal to 1. My attempt at the function is below:

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, active 
                  FROM members 
                                  WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $active);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 
            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked 
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches 
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct 
                    // We record this attempt in the database 
                    $now = time();
                    if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) 
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')")) {
                        header("Location: ../error?err=Database error: login_attempts");
                        exit();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists. 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Could not create a prepared statement
        header("Location: ../error?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
        exit();
    }
}
```

I assume that where I added active to the $mysqli->prepare statement is correct.
What I want to do is if the user got their password correct I would query the MySQL table to see if his account is active(1) or not active(0). If it is set to 0 it logs in with no error. However in my process_login.php file it logs the user in if it is (0) but with index.php?err=1

```
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {

        // Login success 
        header("Location: ../protected_page.php");

        exit();
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
        echo $active;
        exit();
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    header('Location: ../error.php?err=Could not process login');
    exit();
}
```

When I try to echo the variable $active it returns nothing. 
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: this resembles a lot like this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42405324/1415724 where you probably got the same code from http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL and didn't follow it "to a T" - You'll find your answers in those.

Comment: **A:** Follow [that tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) completely without skipping a step or leaving out or modifying any code that will potentially break it. Take this as the solution to this question.

Comment: `header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
        echo $active;` this won't happen btw, not the echo anyway to which you did add that from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki; I don't want rep for it, nor should there be any made from it.

**A:** You did not follow that tutorial exactly as it was written.

- http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

since it is obvious that that is where that code comes from; I know it all too well.

You modified some parts of the code and left some out also.

Go back to the tutorial, and follow it *" **to a T** "*. You may also have to clear out your present hashes and start over.

Make sure that the table creation was done exactly as shown. If you failed to make the right columns and their proper lengths, then that will fail *"silently"* on you.

Consult the comments I left under the question also.